# Open, rotate and sav image

Tags: php, image

I just want to do a simple code that Open, Rotate and Save it back under the same name. I believe that I have found the building blocks in different threads but something is wrong.

```
$filename = './uploads/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$degrees = 180;
// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
// Save
echo imagejpeg($rotate. $filename);
// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

Everything except the save part seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, but I think `echo imagejpeg($rotate. $filename);` is supposed to be `echo imagejpeg($rotate, $filename);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `imagejpeg` call; you need a comma to separate the arguments, instead of a period (which is trying to concatenate the image handle and the filename together as a string).

If you have warnings turned on (always a good idea during development), you would see something like this:

```
PHP Warning:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in something.php on line ...
```